# How to add id or class to a div after updating the database in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

When I update a table, I see I can send a notice saying the table was updated.
What I am thinking about accomplishing is to have the row that was updated to blink a couple of times after I update that specific row.

So for example, I have a controller *accounts* with a *name* and *email*. 
On update, I redirect to the *accounts_url* with the notice *@account.name was updated*.

How can I tell the page which of those rows was updated so I can have the row blink a couple of times?

I am just trying to have fun and learn, so don't be too harsh on the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the updated record id like this to the accounts page:

```rb
redirect_to accounts_url(updated_account_id: @account.id)
```

and in the next page retrieve it from `params[:updated_account_id]` and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to not show the params in the browser? Or is it standard to do it this way? Thanks you so much!

Comment: I set an if statement inside the each loop: "id='updated'" if params[:updated_account_id]  == @account.id. Is that the best approach?

Comment: You can use rails `session` or `flash` (it's like session but you can use it just once and does not persist in other requests) to store the id if you don't want to show it in the url.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of records in your view i think `if` statement is the reasonable approach.